# SSIS Package does not create a file in the shared folder

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, cmd, bcp

**My Environment:**

- SQL Server 2012 BI Edition
- Local Development Machine
- Shared network folders and drives

**What I Want to Achieve:**

- Schedule SSIS Package on SQL Agent that exports 10GB CSV file a few times a week and puts file into the shared folder.

**Actions I've made so far:**

I've created SSIS package that job is simple - to create csv file. The solution works on the local drive and csv files are created. Solution never fails however, csv files are not created when I put destination on shared folder.

The csv file is about 10GB; therefore I use BCP command and *Execute Process Task* as it runs faster.

What have I tried:

1. WorkingDirectory: Local Drive - the solution works
2. WorkingDirectory: Shared Folder - the solution does not fail but files are not created. My account has full permission on the folder.
3. WorkingDirectory: mapped drive using *Net USE* but files were not created.
4. I've deployed the solution and ran SQL Agent Job but files were not created. The server team confirmed that SQL Agent Acount has full permissions on the shared folder.

Please advise how I can use SSIS & BCP command to export csv file to the shared drive on the network.

**Update**

I have used *File System Task* to copy csv file from local folder to network folder and it worked successfully. It does the job for now but it is not ideal. I would like to know why I cannot BCP to the network folder.

Comment: Was the network drive mapped for the account that runs SQL Agent?  Are you using the \\share\folder path?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg - Yes,I've tried both using the path and mapped drive to the same path. I've tried mapping the drive with default settings and for account that runs SQL Agent using: /user:domain\user MyPassword logic.

Comment: Are you attempting to BCP to a non-local folder or are you BCP local and then copying to destination?

Comment: I want to BCP to Non-Local folder but files are not created. I've just tried local and then copy to destination that is working. I will update question shorty

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully you resolved the issue, it could be because networl folder mapping started with \servername , we have to use \\servername.